# Which is the best way for data migration from Shopify to Opencart 3.0.3.1 using CSV files or using API?

Tags: php, shopify, opencart-3

I want to do data migration from Shopify to Opencart. So I want to know which is the best way for data migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be relatively easy to export from Shopify as a CSV and then use this OpenCart extension (or another) to import: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=17

Comment: What if I want to store data in continuation i.e. whatever the new data added into the Shopify will also get added into  the OpenCart.

Comment: That is a different question entirely. You would need a feed from Shopify that OpenCart regularly checks.